# line feed within a column in csv

Tags: csv, unix

I have a csv like below. some of columns have line break like column B below. when I doing wc -l file.csv unix is returning 4 but actually these are 3 records. I don't want to replace line break with space, I am going to load data in database using sql loader and want to load data as it is. what should I do so that unix consider line break as one record?

```
A,B,C,D
1,"hello
world",sds,sds
2,sdsd,sdds,sdds
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're dealing with trivial cases (No quoted fields, no embedded commas, no embedded newlines, etc.), CSV data is best processed with tools that understand the format. Languages like `perl` and `python` have CSV parsing libraries available, there are packages like [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that provide useful utilities, and more.

Using [`csvstat`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvstat.html) from csvkit on your example:

```
$ csvstat -H --count foo.csv
Row count: 3
```